# How to put the amsthm title right of text

Tags: amsthm

How can I put the title of a theorem environment right of the text.

Example:

```
\begin{definition}[Titel]
Some Text
\end{definition}
```

The result should look like this. Where the tile is Strukturbaum
and is placed right of the definition.

[image]

Comment: your image isn't very clear, do you want the title within the text block, or in the margin?

Comment: I think I just found a solution: marginnotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `amsthm` you can define a style that's the same as the standard except for the treatment of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{arweddefinition}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC follows
  {%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
     % no optional argument
   \else
     \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\textwidth}\hspace{\marginparsep}\normalfont\itshape#3}%
   \fi
   \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}%
  }

\theoremstyle{arweddefinition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{definition}[Foo]
A \emph{foo} is something very useful. We will use foos all the
time in this paper. This should be enough to wrap.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
A \emph{baz} is not very useful so we don't set it in the margin.
We will not be using any baz in the paper. This should be enough to wrap.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use a smashed `\parbox` in order to accommodate longer titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{arweddefinition}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC follows
  {%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
     % no optional argument
   \else
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{\textwidth}\hspace{\marginparsep}\normalfont\itshape
       \smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright#3}}%
     }%
   \fi
   \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}%
  }

\theoremstyle{arweddefinition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{definition}[Foo]
A \emph{foo} is something very useful. We will use foos all the
time in this paper. This should be enough to wrap.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
A \emph{baz} is not very useful so we don't set it in the margin.
We will not be using any baz in the paper. This should be enough to wrap.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Strongly typed principal foo]
A \emph{strongly typed principal foo} is not very useful, but we set it in the
margin just by way of example. We will not be using themin the paper. 
This should be enough to wrap.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest I am not completely happy yet with this solution. It the title is too long it will not break.

Comment: @ArwedMett The fix was easy. `;-)`